# Nuxt.js config reuse already loaded fields

Tags: nuxt.js

in my nuxt.config.js I have fields like:

```
authorization_endpoint: process.env.KC_URL+'whatever'
userinfo_endpoint: process.env.KC_URL+'whatever'
```

etc.

I would like to have in one place this KC_URL, tried already ti put it at the top, and use by `this.baseUrl` but this does not work.
can not find any example in docs.

Any ideas ? Thanks!

Comment: nuxt.config.js is just a javascript file, what about create a const outside of the export default and use it then? const baseUrl = process.env.KC_URL; export default { ... authorizationEndpoint: baseUrl + 'whatever', ... } something like this

Comment: ah right, works fine thanks